# The Jacobian of $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y^2,y+x^2)$ under the substitution $u=x+y^2$ and $v=y+x^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

I am given the map $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y^2,y+x^2)$. I am unable to find the Jacobian by making the substitution $u=x+y^2$ and $v=y+x^2$. Any hints would be appreciated.

(I am trying to find whether the map is area preserving? I know "the map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is area and orientation preserving iff the determinant of the Jacobian is $\pm1$".)

Comment: What is the definition of Jacobian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jacobian of a multivariable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ is:

$$\textbf{J}(f(x,y)) = det\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $det$ denotes the determinant of the matrix.

Calculating the partial derivatives of $u(x,y)=x+y^2$ and $v(x,y)=y+x^2$ we have that the Jacobian of your given function is:

$$det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2y \\
2x & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}=1-4xy$$